# Why did Rails ignore my user_id field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, rake, reserved-words

I tried creating a DB migration in Rails that looked something like this:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold post user_id:int title:string content:text
```

Looking at the resulting .rb file, sure enough, I saw everything I'd entered:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.int :user_id # there it is: user_id
      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :posts
  end
end
```

But after running `rake db:migrate` and inspecting my database, I see that no `user_id` column was created. What happened, here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it should be `t.integer`, not `t.int`. See the [docs for more details](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html):

> `add_column(table_name, column_name, type, options)`: Adds a new column to the table called `table_name` named `column_name` specified to be one of the following types: `:string`, `:text`, `:integer`, `:float`, `:decimal`, `:datetime`, `:timestamp`, `:time`, `:date`, `:binary`, `:boolean`.

Comment: Damn, I had a *feeling* it would be something that simple. Thanks! (I'll accept this answer in 10 minutes.)

Comment: This has always bugged me. Why doesn't the migration raise an exception on an invalid column type?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
t.references :user
```

and it will create an integer field called user_id. I personally prefer this method because it's referencing a foreign key.